Is there another way to perform a Like-for-like DAX function based on Stores?
Basically, I am trying to perform a Like-for-like comparison based on Weeks for my Stores performance. So in essence, the DAX should look up for both 2024 and 2023 Week's and search if there are any sales happening on a week basis. If there is 0 sales in that week for either year, mark the store as "Close" otherwise "Open".
Any help would be appreciated!
Sales Status = 
 VAR CurrentWeek = MAX(Overall[Week])
 VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(CurrentWeek)
 VAR LastYear = CurrentYear - 1

VAR SalesThisYear = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Overall[QTY]),
    FILTER(
        Overall,
        Overall[Store Name New] = EARLIER(Overall[Store Name New]) &&
        YEAR(Overall[Week]) = CurrentYear
    )
)

VAR SalesLastYear = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Overall[QTY]),
    FILTER(
        Overall,
        Overall[Store Name New] = EARLIER(Overall[Store Name New]) &&
        YEAR(Overall[Week]) = LastYear
    )
)

RETURN
IF(
    (SalesLastYear > 0 && SalesThisYear = 0) || (SalesThisYear > 0 && SalesLastYear = 0),
    "Close",
    "Open"
)


Is the above a Measure or Calculated Column? What visual are you using for this and what other dimensions are on the visual? This is needed to understand what context are applied (and which ones need to be removed) for the calculations.

This is a Calculated Column. I intend to use it as a Slicer hence a calculated column. In the page, there is a main matrix followed by Bar Graphs. The matrix table (that i want the slicer to change the values) contains Channel and Store Name which will show 2023 and 2024 sales.

You'll need to add some kind of week comparison to your Calculated Column. One way to do this is using WEEKNUM. See the following as an example:
Sales Status = 
 var thisStore = [Store Name New]
 var thisWeek =  [Week]
 var wkNum =  WEEKNUM(thisWeek)
 var thisYear = YEAR(thisWeek)
 var prevYear = thisYear - 1

 var salesThisYear = 
   CALCULATE(
    SUM(Overall[QTY]),
    FILTER(
      Overall,
      Overall[Store Name New] = thisStore &&
      YEAR(Overall[Week]) = thisYear &&
      WEEKNUM(Overall[Week]) = wkNum 
    )
  )

 var salesPrevYear = 
   CALCULATE(
    SUM(Overall[QTY]),
    FILTER(
      Overall,
      Overall[Store Name New] = thisStore &&
      YEAR(Overall[Week]) = prevYear &&
      WEEKNUM(Overall[Week]) = wkNum 
    )
  )

 RETURN
   IF (salesThisYear = 0 || salesPrevYear = 0, "Close", "Open")

